how to keep a command window open after run a batch file?
When I run a compilation command from batch file, the command did execute but after it completed, the command window close immediately
I'm expecting the result shows in the command window after compilation has been completed

you can either start the batch file from cmd.exe (instead of double clicking it in the file explorer), or you can end the batch file with a command that asks for user input

This question is similar to: Keep CMD open after BAT file executes. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem. Please spend at least 5 minutes googling your problems...

Just append to your batch file an instruction that requires you to press a key before moving forward. Try this:
echo Press any key to exit...  
pause 

Reference here
